# Eject CD (command) without aborting install

Tags: debian, optical-media

I'm working on a debian server, and my repositories are on 5 separate DVDs. While installing new programs, I'm often prompted to insert a different disc. The eject button on my cd drive is generally unresponsive, so I've taken to using the 'eject' command. Unfortunately, if I use 'eject' in the middle of an install (ie; when it prompts me to change disks), it will abort the install, and I'll wind up a partial install (Which gets messy). How do I eject the cd drive through a command without aborting the install?

Comment: problems like this are why it'll *never* be the year of Linux on the desktop.